# Where/how can I find a listing of prices for in-flight WiFi usage on Qatar Airways?

Tags: air-travel, wifi, qatar-airways

I have a bunch of upcoming 6+ hours long flights [on Qatar Airways' new aircraft which have on-board WiFi](http://www.qatarairways.com/uk/en/onboard-connectivity.page) from Oryx Communications. Is there any way I can find out in advance what the costs are for using this service?

Comment: [This Qatar Airways FAQ](http://qatarairways.zendesk.com/entries/104523813-What-are-the-charges-incurred-to-use-Wi-Fi-on-board-a-Qatar-Airways-flight-and-are-all-major-credit-) suggest that the price varies depending on the plane you're on...

Comment: [This loyalty lobby piece on problems with the Qatar A380 wifi internet](http://loyaltylobby.com/2014/12/12/review-qatar-airways-a380-bkk-doh-onair-wifi-internet/) features some pricing info, which might be a guide, but also suggests you shouldn't plan on it actually being in any way usable...

Comment: @Gagravarr I just noticed that I have used the same blog entry as the one you suggested here, It was sincerely pure luck that I got the result from Google and not from your comment which I just noticed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this blog entry](http://loyaltylobby.com/2014/12/12/review-qatar-airways-a380-bkk-doh-onair-wifi-internet/) (screenshots of the signup page available), the prices are:

**For Laptops**

- 20MB for $10 USD
- 50MB for $18 USD
- Full Flight for $22

**For Mobile**

- 12MB for $5 USD
- 5MB for $2 USD
- 3 Hours for $10 USD

It is worth mentioning that the blog owner had a bad experience using the onboard wifi as most of the requests were timed out and pages were not loading. I personally had better experiences in other airlines using this service. So, I guess it totally depends on the strength of the Inmarsat satellite's signal.

Comment: The price differs based on the aircraft, as per [Qatar Airways FAQ](http://qatarairways.zendesk.com/entries/104523813-What-are-the-charges-incurred-to-use-Wi-Fi-on-board-a-Qatar-Airways-flight-and-are-all-major-credit-), so not sure how reliable the above is.

Comment: Consistent with the prices I saw, without the hourly options. I'm going to mark this as accepted for now for the lack of a better answer.

Comment: [This blog post from a journey from a couple of weeks ago](http://economyclassandbeyond.boardingarea.com/2015/07/29/the-five-yen-of-happiness-qatar-airways-frankfurt-to-doha-aboard-the-airbus-a350/) has the A350 prices about half way down. They seem to match the prices John found on his A380 flight

Comment: And [this post from the same trip](http://economyclassandbeyond.boardingarea.com/2015/08/04/the-five-yen-of-happiness-qatar-airways-flight-qr812-hamad-international-airport-doha-to-tokyo-haneda/) has the B787 pricing in it around half way down, which seems to lack the time based / full flight options